# Set ggplot2 limits as relative ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I have 50+ graphs to produce (plotting averages of lots of variables one by one) and was asked to normalize the scale range : i.e. the minimum and maximum value can vary but I want the difference between ymin and ymax to remain the same (say, 100)

here's an example :

```
#this works :

works<-mtcars%>%ggplot(aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+stat_summary(geom="line",size=2,col="blue",fun="mean")+ylim(mean(mtcars$mpg)-50,mean(mtcars$mpg)+50) 

works
```

```
#this does not :
mtcars%>%ggplot(aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+stat_summary(geom="line",size=2,col="blue",fun="mean")+ylim(mean(.data$y)-50,mean(.data$y)+50)

# neither does this

mtcars%>%ggplot(aes(x=wt,y=hp))+stat_summary(geom="line",size=2,col="blue",fun="mean")+ylim(ymin,ymin+100)
```

I would like to avoid calling the variable directly as I have a lot of them but rather either a transformation of the y aesthethic  or the keep the automatic ggplot scaling as "ymin" (ggplots calculates it somewhere for automatic cropping and a ggplot is  a list so this element should be callable somehow) and call ymax  relative to ymin or (even better but not sure it exists) specify automatic limits as a range (like "I want it centered +- something" ) and keep "something" constant among all my graphs

do you have any idea ?

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tidy way to do this would be to define your own `ggplot_add` method:

```r
add_range <- function(range) {
  structure(list(range = range), class = 'expander')
 }

ggplot_add.expander <- function(obj, p, name) {
  p + ylim(mean(sapply(ggplot_build(p)$data, function(x) mean(x$y))) + obj$range)
}
```

This then allows you to use whatever range above and below the mean of the data you like with an easy-to-use syntax:

```r
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "line", size = 2, col = "blue", fun = "mean") +
  add_range(c(-50, 50))
```

[image]

Comment: whoops  I realize that the part of my example which works uses wt and not mpg in the ylim call, i'll correct it. It's  working but what I would actually like is a level of abstraction such that I do not have to write the name of the y variable at all because I have hundreds of them, so referring to it as "the y aesthetic" and not " the variable x" .

I'm not sure it exists and I could do it by hand but I think it would be a nice feature/trick to know

Comment: @Maxence if you are able to process the plots after they are created / stored, then this is much easier. Is that an option?

Comment: @Maxence see my update for a more elegant solution that is easy to apply to multiple plots.

Comment: I like it a lot, but it does not seem to work for me as when I define  the second function I get:
Error: unexpected input in:
"ggplot_add.expander <- function(obj, p, name) {
  p + ylim(mean(sapply(ggplot_build(p)$data, \"
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"

Is there some requirement to define a ggplot method ?

Comment: @Maxence if you are using an older version of R, the `\(x)` syntax won't work for you - that needs to be `function(x)` instead. I'll update my answer (though you should consider updating R to the latest version if possible)

Comment: Yes, once uptdated to 4.2 it work as envisionned, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the `scale_y_continuous()` function instead of `ylim()`. Its argument *limits* can accept a function changing existing, default limits. See the example below.

```
mtcars%>%
ggplot(aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+
stat_summary(geom="line",size=2,col="blue",fun="mean")+
scale_y_continuous(limits = function(lim){c(lim[1]-50,lim[2]+50)})
```

Comment: not exactly what I had in mind but you allowed me to find the solution, from your code I get that there exist a lim element storing the min and max values of y. 

What I need is then just `mtcars%>%
ggplot(aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+
stat_summary(geom="line",size=2,col="blue",fun="mean")+
scale_y_continuous(limits = function(lim){c(lim[1],lim[1]+100)})`

maybe I'll try to fiddle a bit with coord also (to not delete oob observations) THX anyway !